# Java Swing: How does using a JTable work?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to build a little Table to show appointments.
Here is what I have so far. Maybe you can give me a hint about what I am doing wrong, or which way to go.

```
            public class AppointmentTable extends JFrame{


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JTable table = new JTable(new AppointmentTableModel(10, 6, new   ArrayList<Appointment>()));
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            AppointmentTable  frame = new AppointmentTable();
            frame.add(scrollPane);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    public class AppointmentTable extends JFrame{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTable table = new JTable(new AppointmentTableModel(10, 6, new ArrayList<Appointment>()));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        AppointmentTable  frame = new AppointmentTable();
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    }

    public class AppointmentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private int columns;
        private int rows;
        ArrayList<Appointment> appointments;

        public AppointmentTableModel(int columns, int rows,
                ArrayList<Appointment> appointments) {
            this.columns = columns;
            this.rows = rows;
            this.appointments = appointments;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {

            return columns;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {

            return rows;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

            return appointments.get(rowIndex).getByColumn(columnIndex);
        }
    }

public class Appointment {

    private Date date;
    private Sample sample;
    private String comment;
    private ArrayList<Action> history;

    public Appointment(Date date, Sample sample, String comment) {
        this.date = date;
        this.sample = sample;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.history = new ArrayList<Action>();
    }

    public Object getByColumn(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0: return date;

        case 1: return date;

        case 2: return sample;

        case 3: return sample;

        case 4: return history;

        case 5: return comment;


        }
        return null;
    }

}
public class Action {
String action;

public Action(String act){
    this.action=act;
}

}
```

Comment: The best advice someone can give you on that one (but that is not a direct answer to the problem with your code) would be to use GlazedLists (open source) that will provide the model for you.
Note that this is good practice to use Java Beans for your Appointment class (with get/set methods) rather than using a getByColumn() that mixes the GUI (column index in a table) with the business (Appointment data).

Answer (score 1):

First, your model's `getRowCount()` method is incorrect, it should be

```
public int getRowCount() {
  return appointments.size();
}
```

Then, you're passing an empty appointment list to your model, so the table shows nothing!

```
JTable table = new JTable(new AppointmentTableModel(10, 6, new ArrayList<Appointment>()));
```

Initialize your list with some data before creating the table.